# PHPDoc to assign @param as a referened @property

Tags: php, phpdoc

I'm trying to define a param for a method as being the ID field from another class. Basically this idea...

```
/**
 * @param \Database\Member::id $memberId
 * @return MemberEntity
 */
public function getMember( int $memberId ) : MemberEntity
{
...
}
```

the `@see` command doesn't seem to be the right solution for this. Is there something I'm missing here? The PHPDoc website is surprisingly minimal...

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The @param tag receives the values: type, name and description. Apparently the type of your variable is int. If the \Database\Member::id attribute is not a native type of php or a class, it can not be used that way. So it is not possible to do this type of reference you want in traditional PHPDoc.

`Syntax
@param [Type] [name] [<description>]`

Comment: yeah that `id` field would be an `int` variable, but my goal is for the phpdoc to point to what that int belongs to. The same concept as a foreign key in a database, but somehow using phpdoc. This would be used so that a code generator can be aware of what object to get that id field value from. must be some solution in phpdoc, somehow...

Comment: You can get the reflection through the PHPDoc value and work with it.

`
$reflection = ReflectionClass('Member');
$doc = $reflection->getDocComent();
`

The term related to what you want to do is "annotation". Libraries to help exist, like this one: https://php-annotations.readthedocs.io/en/latest/UsingAnnotations.html